# I want to make simple request with signalR yet this seems very complex to me

Tags: node.js, signalr

//I try to do it with nodeJS  npm i signalr-client
So I want to retrieve data.
[image]

Comment: try to use request module instead if you can change the module

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can do it, however I need websockets

Comment: Take a look at these two. I hope it helps. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-socket-in-nodejs/amp/  or https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61